# Problem when concat results of query to single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure:

```
| ROLE_ID | PERMISSION_ID |
+---------+---------------+
|   1     |    12         |
|   2     |    12         |
|   2     |    13         |
|   2     |    14         |
|   1     |    13         |
```

My query return error

> Column 'USER_ROLE_PERMISSION.PERMISSION_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

because PERMISSION_ID is not in aggregate function:

```
DECLARE @CodeNameString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CodeNameString = NULL

SELECT 
    @CodeNameString = COALESCE(@CodeNameString + ', ', '') + 
                      CAST(PERMISSION_ID AS VARCHAR) 
FROM
    USER_ROLE_PERMISSION 
GROUP BY    
    ROLE_ID

SELECT 
    @CodeNameString, ROLE_ID    
FROM
    USER_ROLE_PERMISSION
GROUP BY
    ROLE_ID
```

I want to get result like:

```
| ROLE_ID | PERMISSION_ID |
+---------+---------------+
|   1     |  12,13        |
|   2     |  12,13,14     |
```

I need to concat `PERMISSION_ID` based on its `ROLE_ID`. But as you can see, `PERMISSION_ID` is outside the aggregate function so I need to group it by `PERMISSION_ID` as well. How if I want to group it only by `ROLE_ID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the best approach to get what you want.  Instead, use the XML method for concatenation:

```
select r.role_id,
       stuff( (select ',' + convert(varchar(max), permission_id)
               from user_role_permission urp
               where urp.role_id = r.role_id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
             ) as permissions
from (select distinct role_id from user_role_permission) r;
```